# Add CORS headers on 5XX responses from API Gateway with Lambda proxy integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda proxy integration with API Gateway that is working fine.

CORS is handled directly in the lambda code with checks against lists of authorized domains.

But the issue now is with unexpected errors during Lambda execution.

API Gateway returns the following message in such a case:

```
{
    message: "Internal server error"
}
```

with a `502` HTTP status code. Unfortunately for me, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing in that response, which is causing errors on client side.

The same happens also with timeouts for example. The HTTP status code is then `504` but the response content and the lack of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is the same.

The same issue occurs also in case of permission issue: if the API Gateway does not have sufficient permissions to call the Lambda, then a `500` error is returned but, once again, without any header.

A fixed value of `'*'` would be OK in the case of Lambda errors but how and where can this be configured?

Comment: I'm having the same problem: no CORS headers when API GateWay cannot launch the lambda (i.e. pauyload too large). Have you found a solution? If so, post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game, but you can add these to your SAM / CloudFormation template to fix this:

```
Resources:
  GatewayResponseDefault4XX:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
    Properties:
      ResponseParameters:
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      ResponseType: DEFAULT_4XX
      RestApiId:
        Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
  GatewayResponseDefault5XX:
    Type: 'AWS::ApiGateway::GatewayResponse'
    Properties:
      ResponseParameters:
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
         gatewayresponse.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "'*'"
      ResponseType: DEFAULT_5XX
      RestApiId:
        Ref: 'ApiGatewayRestApi'
```

Taken from here: [https://serverless-stack.com/chapters/handle-api-gateway-cors-errors.html#create-a-resource][1]

Comment: i have added this and in API gateway Gateway Responses the headers are populated. but after some times the headers are not returned

Answer (score -1):

Add in your handler function this callback with these values, you can add your proper response in the body

```
callback(null, {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
          "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ "response": true })
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ahmad, but everything is fine when the lambda gets executed completely. The error I have is with unexpected errors during Lambda executions...